# How to modify layers of pretrained models in Keras like Inception-v3?

Tags: python, keras, models

I want to use Inception-v3 with pretrained weights on ImageNet to take inputs that are not just 3 channel RGB images but have more channels, such that the dimension is *(224, 224, x!=3)*, and then assigning a self-defined set of weights to the following Conv2D layer. I was trying to change the input layer and the subsequent Conv2D layer such that it suits my needs, but I could not find a structured way of doing so.

I tried building a custom Conv2d tensor with **Conv2D(...)(input)** and assigning that to the corresponding layer of Inception, but this fails because it requires actual layers, while the above instruction yields a tensor. For all it matters, **Conv2D(...)(Input)** and **Inception.layers[1].output** yields the correct same output (which it should be since I just want to change the input dimensions and weights), the question is how to wrap the new Conv2D input-output mapping as a layer and replace it in Inception?

I could try hacking my way through this, but generally I wondered if there is a swift and elegant way of reassigning certain layers in those pretrained models with custom specifications.

Thank you!

Edit:
What works is inserting these lines at line 394 of the inception_v3.py from Keras, disabling the exception for more than 3 channel inputs and then simply calling the constructor with the desired input. (Note that **Original calls the original InceptionV3 constructor**)

Code:

```
original_model = Original(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape=(299, 299, 3))
weights = model.get_weights()
original_weights = original_model.get_weights()

for i in range(1, len(original_weights)):
       weights[i] = original_weights[i]
averaged_weights = np.mean(weights[0], axis=2)[:, :, None, :]
replicated_weights = np.repeat(averaged_weights, 20, axis=2)
weights[0] = replicated_weights
```

Then I can call

```
InceptionV3(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape=(299, 299, 20))
```

This work and gives the desired result, but seems very hacky.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you share your code to help the community with more detail?

Comment: Is this the code you are referring to? - https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/applications/inception_v3.py         The line numbers seems to have changed. Where exactly are you changing the code?

Comment: I get the following error when I do that - ValueError: Dimension 0 in both shapes must be equal, but are 3 and 32. Shapes are [3,3,20,32] and [32,3,3,3]. for 'Assign_890' (op: 'Assign') with input shapes: [3,3,20,32], [32,3,3,3].

Comment: Got my mistake. A few more modifications to your hack did the trick for me, I now have a model that can take input with more than 3 channels. Thank you!

Comment: Shouldn't that last line be "InceptionV3(weights=weights, include_top=False, input_shape=(299, 299, 20))"?